# Get the Size of a CSS Background Image Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, image

Is it possible to use JavaScript to get the actual size (width and height in pixels) of a CSS referenced background image?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, and I'd do it like this...

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var imageSrc = document
    .getElementById('hello')
    .style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
    .split(',')[0];

  // I just broke it up on newlines for readability

  var image = new Image();
  image.src = imageSrc;

  image.onload = function () {
    var width = image.width,
      height = image.height;
    alert('width =' + width + ', height = ' + height);
  };
};
```

Some notes...

- We need to remove the `url()` part that JavaScript returns to get the proper image source. We need to split on `,` in case the element has multiple background images.
- We make a new `Image` object and set its `src` to the new image.
- We can then read the width & height.

jQuery would probably a lot less of a headache to get going.

Comment: Code posted here and code on JSbin are different. Your regexp in replace has a bug. Here more correct version `.replace(/url\(['"]?(.*)['"]?\)/gi, '$1')`

Comment: this does not handle data urls because of the `split`. I removed the split as I only use a single background, but otherwise an additional `if` statement needs to be used to check the presence of `data:`

Comment: @Timmerz Wouldn't a data URI imply that the image would already be loaded?

Comment: @alex I'm not sure what you mean? your function gets the size of a `background-image` by copying it to an `Image`. I'm saying this won't work if the `background-image` references a data url instead of a hyperlink.

Comment: @Timmerz Sorry, I had a few tabs open and wasn't in the correct context when I replied.

Comment: alex in order to get the width and height you need to wait until the image  is loaded. no? Thanks to @Killah answer I added it to my code before the src line and now everything works.

Comment: @RandallFlagg This is under `window.onload`, so all images should be loaded.

Comment: @alex but you created a new Image and gave it a new source.  If you change the source, even after everything was loaded, that means the image is reloading and thus meaning  you need to wait before accessing the properties of the image.

Comment: @RandallFlagg The source is from an existing image on the page. Unless you have disabled cache, it should be available.

I do see what you're getting at though. I guess it would be safer to use a `load` listener again before checking the dimensions.

Comment: After researching this question for a couple of hours, this is the easiest and fastest way to do it.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir then you'd [ask that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Alex, I used your script om [this page](http://ascetic.rol.ro/slander/) to calculate the w/h ratio and add a css rule if ratio < 1. But unless i reload the page the script returns NaN.

Comment: `document.getElementById('hello').attributes.src.value` works for me

Comment: @ZacharyRyanSmith I just tried it with a background image and it appeared the `src` property wasn't defined on `attributes`. Are you sure it's a background image, not a normal `img` element?

Comment: @alex you're correct, it was a normal `img` element.  Sorry, I was not thinking about `img` vs background-image

Comment: You should set the width and height in an `image.onload` handler; if you don't do this the width/height can be 0 if your internet connection is slow or the image is big.

Comment: @thdoan Doesn't `window.onload` guarantee that the page has finished loading, images and all?

Answer (score 14):

Can't comment under answers, so here is jQuery version including `background-size` (posted because this question is first one in google search and may be useful to someone else than me):

```
function getBackgroundSize(selector, callback) {
  var img = new Image(),
      // here we will place image's width and height
      width, height,
      // here we get the size of the background and split it to array
      backgroundSize = $(selector).css('background-size').split(' ');

  // checking if width was set to pixel value
  if (/px/.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = parseInt(backgroundSize[0]);
  // checking if width was set to percent value
  if (/%/.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = $(selector).parent().width() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);
  // checking if height was set to pixel value
  if (/px/.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = parseInt(backgroundSize[1]);
  // checking if height was set to percent value
  if (/%/.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = $(selector).parent().height() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);

  img.onload = function () {
    // check if width was set earlier, if not then set it now
    if (typeof width == 'undefined') width = this.width;
    // do the same with height
    if (typeof height == 'undefined') height = this.height;
    // call the callback
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
  }
  // extract image source from css using one, simple regex
  // src should be set AFTER onload handler
  img.src = $(selector).css('background-image').replace(/url\(['"]*(.*?)['"]*\)/g, '$1');
}
```

or as jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
// for better performance, define regexes once, before the code
var pxRegex = /px/, percentRegex = /%/, urlRegex = /url\(['"]*(.*?)['"]*\)/g;
$.fn.getBackgroundSize = function (callback) {
  var img = new Image(), width, height, backgroundSize = this.css('background-size').split(' ');

  if (pxRegex.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = parseInt(backgroundSize[0]);
  if (percentRegex.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = this.parent().width() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);
  if (pxRegex.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = parseInt(backgroundSize[1]);
  if (percentRegex.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = this.parent().height() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);
  // additional performance boost, if width and height was set just call the callback and return
  if ((typeof width != 'undefined') && (typeof height != 'undefined')) {
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
    return this;
  }
  img.onload = function () {
    if (typeof width == 'undefined') width = this.width;
    if (typeof height == 'undefined') height = this.height;
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
  }
  img.src = this.css('background-image').replace(urlRegex, '$1');
  return this;
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Lovely! The jQuery plugin worked perfectly for me. Everyone, this function gives the scaled image size. Thanks very much!

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, it gives the _unscaled_ image size. But I still like it!

Comment: There's a potential bug in that regexp. Here's the correct one:
`urlRegex = /url\(['"]*(.*?)['"]*\)/g`

Comment: @neochief thanks, fixed that, totally forgot someone can use `"` in the `url()`

Comment: Сouldn't you explain how to use it? Or give an example. Both the function and the plugin. Thanks.

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden dude, I added a jQuery version for reasons stated at the beginning of the answer. Go on your jQuery-hate-spree somewhere else, nobody needs zealots here.

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden At the time of writing this answer this question popped up as first in Google search for "jQuery get background size" and similar. If a teacher has to look things up on SO then I don't think that person should be teaching anyone. I was at your stage - hating on jQuery. Then I grew up. Stop spamming - your last comment was removed already.

Comment: `height = $(selector).parent().height() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100); ` --> should use `backgroundSize[1]` instead `backgroundSize[0] `
 // 
`width = $(selector).parent().width() * `
`height = $(selector).parent().height() * `
--> 
Should use `$(selector).width` and `$(selector).height`, not parent's

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko 9 years and nobody noticed a typo :D feel free to use the edit feature to fix it, so you get credit for spotting it. Sadly I don't remember anymore why `.parent()` was needed, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I did edit it. But the reviewers https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626245/dave and https://stackoverflow.com/users/15744300/jan-wilamowski said in a single word "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."
Have they not read through my comment on Aug 29, 2021 at 2:17 and the author's comment to it? The author @klh said: "feel free to use the edit feature to fix it, so you get credit for spotting it."
I had another bad experience.

Comment: I wrote the revised code as a new answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
var actualImage = new Image();
actualImage.src = $('YOUR SELECTOR HERE').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

actualImage.onload = function() {
    width = this.width;
    height = this.height;
}
```

Comment: What if the background image is scaled and you want to get the scaled width and height values?

Answer (score 5):

```
var dimension, image;

image = new Image();
image.src = {url/data}
image.onload = function() {
    dimension = {
        width: image.naturalWidth,
        height: image.naturalHeight
    };
    console.log(dimension); // Actual image dimension
};
```

Comment: Despite how old this question and this answer is, this is what worked for me. I also edited the answer to fix a syntax issue and used Killah's helpful regex expression in setting the image.src variable.

Comment: using 'naturalWidth' and 'naturalHeight' works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in jQuery:

```
var actualImage = new Image();
actualImage.src = $('YOUR SELECTOR HERE').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

actualImage.width // The actual image width
actualImage.height // The actual image height
```

Thanks for the sweet regex alex.

Comment: Except that this doesn't work in Chrome. FF seems to load the image but Chrome doesn't. So the width and height properties of actualImage are always 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React you can create a custom hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'

const urlRgx = /url\((['"])?(.+?)\1\)/
const getImagePromise = src =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image()

    img.onload = () =>
      resolve({
        src,
        width: img.naturalWidth,
        height: img.naturalHeight
      })
    img.src = src
  })
const useBackgroundImageSize = (asCallbackFlagOrUrls = false) => {
  const ref = useRef()
  const [images, setImages] = useState(null)
  const callback = useCallback(async () => {
    if (Array.isArray(asCallbackFlagOrUrls)) {
      const imgPromises = asCallbackFlagOrUrls.map(getImagePromise)
      const imgs = await Promise.all(imgPromises)

      if (ref?.current) {
        setImages(imgs)
      }
    }

    if (typeof asCallbackFlagOrUrls === 'string') {
      const image = await getImagePromise(asCallbackFlagOrUrls)

      if (ref?.current) {
        setImages(image)
      }
    }

    if (typeof asCallbackFlagOrUrls === 'boolean') {
      if (ref.current) {
        const matches = window
          .getComputedStyle(ref.current)
          .backgroundImage.match(new RegExp(urlRgx, 'g'))

        if (Array.isArray(matches)) {
          const imgPromises = matches.map(match =>
            getImagePromise(match.replace(new RegExp(urlRgx), '$2'))
          )
          const imgs = await Promise.all(imgPromises)

          if (ref?.current) {
            setImages(imgs.length > 1 ? imgs : imgs[0])
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, [ref, asCallbackFlagOrUrls])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asCallbackFlagOrUrls !== true) {
      callback()
    }
  }, [asCallbackFlagOrUrls, callback])

  return asCallbackFlagOrUrls === true ? [ref, images, callback] : [ref, images]
}

export { useBackgroundImageSize }
```

Then use it like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [ref, image] = useBackgroundImageSize()

  console.log(image) // { width, height, src }

  return <div ref={ref} image={image} />
}
```

You can also install [background-image-size-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/background-image-size-hook) and use it as a dependency. See the [README](https://github.com/morganney/background-image-size-hook#readme) for more usage details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of the code from [klh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930007/klh)'s post.
I pointed out some small mistakes on the comment section of his post and was told please edit it.
And so I did.
However, reviewers [Jan Wilamowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15744300/jan-wilamowski) and [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626245/dave) rejected it.

> "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Apparently they did not see the comments section.

I had no choice but to write the revised code as a new answer.

```
function getBackgroundSize(selector, callback) {
  var img = new Image(),
      // here we will place image's width and height
      width, height,
      // here we get the size of the background and split it to array
      backgroundSize = $(selector).css('background-size').split(' ');

  // checking if width was set to pixel value
  if (/px/.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = parseInt(backgroundSize[0]);
  // checking if width was set to percent value
  if (/%/.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = $(selector).width() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);
  // checking if height was set to pixel value
  if (/px/.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = parseInt(backgroundSize[1]);
  // checking if height was set to percent value
  if (/%/.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = $(selector).height() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[1]) / 100);

  img.onload = function () {
    // check if width was set earlier, if not then set it now
    if (typeof width == 'undefined') width = this.width;
    // do the same with height
    if (typeof height == 'undefined') height = this.height;
    // call the callback
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
  }
  // extract image source from css using one, simple regex
  // src should be set AFTER onload handler
  img.src = $(selector).css('background-image').replace(/url\(['"]*(.*?)['"]*\)/g, '$1');
}
```

JQuery

```
(function ($) {
// for better performance, define regexes once, before the code
var pxRegex = /px/, percentRegex = /%/, urlRegex = /url\(['"]*(.*?)['"]*\)/g;
$.fn.getBackgroundSize = function (callback) {
  var img = new Image(), width, height, backgroundSize = this.css('background-size').split(' ');

  if (pxRegex.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = parseInt(backgroundSize[0]);
  if (percentRegex.test(backgroundSize[0])) width = this.width() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[0]) / 100);
  if (pxRegex.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = parseInt(backgroundSize[1]);
  if (percentRegex.test(backgroundSize[1])) height = this.height() * (parseInt(backgroundSize[1]) / 100);
  // additional performance boost, if width and height was set just call the callback and return
  if ((typeof width != 'undefined') && (typeof height != 'undefined')) {
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
    return this;
  }
  img.onload = function () {
    if (typeof width == 'undefined') width = this.width;
    if (typeof height == 'undefined') height = this.height;
    callback({ width: width, height: height });
  }
  img.src = this.css('background-image').replace(urlRegex, '$1');
  return this;
}
})(jQuery);
```