# How to set a div size to its background image size

Tags: css

```
<div class="newsBlocks"></div>
```

css:

```
.newsBlocks{ 
    background: url(../img/news/1.png);
}
```

How to set my div to the size of 1.png?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to auto-size a div based on the size of it's background image, but you could do it this very (hacky) way, by including an `img` tag with the url to the image, setting the `img` to `visibility:hidden;` [used inline CSS for brevity - don't kill me!]:

```
<div style="background-image: url('img.jpg');">
    <img src="img.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it statically by manually setting the CSS of the div to the height and width of the image, otherwise you can do it dynamically by using Javascript to get the height and width of the background image as detailed here: [Get the Size of a CSS Background Image Using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098404/get-the-size-of-a-css-background-image-using-javascript)