# CSS: Make a background-image appear without having content and/or fixed sizes?

Tags: html, image, css

I've got this code (with no header-image visible) so far:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/940/248');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you give the header-image a fixed size of 248px you can see it appear. Example with visible header-image:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/940/248');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 248px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it appear without using a fixed height?

Like when using a classic img-tag with just src- and alt-attribute. Then height is read out of the image-file self.

I would like to avoid fixed heights in there because if the image changes then it becomes all wrong.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer on [how to get div height to auto-adjust to background size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/600743/3162554). If it is fine for you to add the `<img>` to the HTML it will fit your needs. Otherwise you would need javascript to [get the size of a CSS background image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3098404/3162554) and change the divs height dynamically then.

Comment: @Marvin Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to define a height if using background-image. Might be better to use img tag and just put a width of 100%, like so:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {
  border: 3px solid white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns header">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/940/248" alt="Bear Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I guess you are right. Greetings from Saarland.